# Where is the suspend/hibernate button in GNOME Shell?

Tags: suspend, hibernate, gnome-shell

In 17.04 I could suspend\hibernate from the power off menu button.

I can't find how to do this in Ubuntu 17.10 GNOME Shell.

Comment: Press the 'alt' key while you are looking at the drop down menu.  Sort of like running a Mac

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-exit.html#suspend

Comment: Wow! they did a really good job at hiding it!

Comment: As regards hibernate, it wasn't enabled by default in Ubuntu, and I don't think there is such a menu option at all on GNOME.

Comment: After finding the `suspend` button, why it's [not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966990/17-10-gnome-suspend-via-alt-key)? another problem.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

**Option 1**

Hold "Alt" when in the menu, this will switch the **power off** button into **suspend** button.

---

**Option 2**

When in the menu, click and hold on the **power off** button until it turns into **suspend** button.

---

**Option 3**

- Go to settings
- Choose **Power**
- At the bottom, choose for the value **Suspend** for the **When the Power Button is pressed**

Now you can just click the power button to suspend.

[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer...  Also, if you click on the shutdown button, and hold the mouse button there for a few milliseconds, the shutdown button changes into a suspend (two vertical bars) button, so you don't necessarily have to press the Alt key.

Comment: I do not have a details menu with those items there

Comment: I used to be like that but now ALT button does not do anything. After adding some features to panel this feature disappeared!

Comment: Anybody can explain the rational behind this odd GUI setup?  If a user has to search the web to suspend his/her computer, it is definitively not user friendly.

Comment: @HansDeragon Indeed! Seems to be Gnome 3 in a nutshell... :-/

Comment: Very nice, surprisingly clean. I like it when I don't have to edit some settings or config file. The less customized my computer is, the better.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question for the Sleep button on many PCs. This button suspends by default.

Comment: I really want to find the email thread to understand this design.

Comment: @HansDeragon the rationale is that they did not read the book "Don't make me think"

Answer (score 54):

There isn't any, Welcome to GNOME!

But like in most of the other cases there's an extension which adds one: [Suspend Button](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/826/suspend-button/). It

> Allows to modify the suspend/shutdown button in the status menu.

[image]
 (screenshot source: extension's homepage at extensions.gnome.org)

Alternatively, if you press <kbd>alt</kbd>, the power button should change to the suspend ("pause" symbol) button.

Comment: I used to be like that but now ALT button does not do anything. After adding some features to panel this feature disappeared!

Comment: even more useful (what is actually shown in the screenshot) is the Lock and Suspend extension, which also adds the Lock button.  Why one would need to add an extension to have something that obvious, is something that only Gnome designers will ever know...

Comment: @Marco I don't understand completely, which extension are you talking about?  Lock button is there by default, I don't think any extension is needed for that. Also strictly speaking, installing the extensions is not at all necessary, the holding <Alt> key trick (seems to be intended way, cloning a feature from Mac) as mentioned here and also many other solutions from other answers (for example [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/1136037/480481)) don't require any extensions.

Comment: What I meant that there are actually *two* extensions: the one pointed at by the link (which only adds the Suspend button) and the one I mentioned (which adds both - as depicted in the screenshot).  The point is moot, however, as in Ubuntu 19.04 *neither works* and using the Alt button (which is unintuitive and, IMHO, unnecessary, as there's plenty of room in that panel) is _the only viable option_.

Comment: and, ummm, "cloning a feature from Mac"? not sure what you mean: I've been using MacOS for >10 years now, I don't recall ever having to use Alt - just hit Apple menu, then you can choose `Sleep`/`Restart...`/`Shut down`.  Maybe it was there ages ago, but someone at Apple may have correctly figured out it made no sense whatsoever, perhaps.

Comment: @Marco TBH I cannot back that up. I don't use Mac, I just saw the [first comment below the question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967205/where-is-the-suspend-hibernate-button-in-gnome-shell/967207?noredirect=1#comment1548641_967205). Perhaps misunderstood it. I don't have 19.04 either. Could you check whether [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1136037/480481) works with 19.04 too?

Answer (score 13):

On newer GNOME versions (v3.26 or higher, so Ubuntu 17.10 and later), you can suspend from the '*Activities*' overview. Simply click the "Activities" button or press <kbd>Super</kbd> and search for "suspend", an icon should appear:
[image]
Click it to suspend your system.

---

Note that you can also perform other actions like shutdown, logout, screen locking in the same way.

Comment: Best way! Thanks

Answer (score 11):

You can add a keyboard shortcut for suspend action like below:

1. Go to settings -> keyboard
2. Click on `+` sign at the bottom of page to set a custom shortcut
3. Enter shortcut name as `Sleep` and command as `/bin/systemctl suspend`
4. Now click on set shortcut button and set a keyboard shortcut

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks.  Wouldn't have found that plus sign way down at the bottom or known what command to use without this.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you can do it in two steps:

first you lock your session with the lock icon from the "power" menu, then you reach again the same menu from the lock screen, and it proposes the suspend icon this time.

Weird and confusing...

Comment: Just FYI, this is no longer possible in 19.04, as the "Lock" button is gone too. I mean, I love Ubuntu, and really happy they got back to Gnome, but honestly, some design choices really leave me wondering...

Comment: Thank you Marco, I just edited my answer with that information. So yep, Ubuntu doesn't seem to get better over time, nowadays

Comment: my bad - figured out that there is a setting in "Unity Tweaks" that disables the lock screen (I cannot recally my setting this - why would I?) but disabling the button that disables it (if there's ever a weird UI setting is that one...) gives me back the "Lock" icon and I can now lock the screen. (incidentally, this is also possible via a keyboard shortcut: default is Ctrl-Alt-Home, but can be changed).

Comment: Simply long-press the 'alt' key while you are looking at the shutdown button, it will change to suspend button :)

Answer (score 3):

Our house has 3 Ubuntu 18.04 desktop systems and while we often use suspend
we rarely use power off so here is our shortcut.

```
# Provide desktop shortcut to suspend command. 
# A solution for Ubuntu 18.04 gnome somewhat hidden mouse nav to suspend.
# Place file in ~/Desktop/Suspend.desktop
# and chmod a+x ~/Desktop/Suspend.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Icon=/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/24x24/emotes/face-cool.png
Name=Suspend
Exec=/bin/systemctl suspend
Categories=Utility
```