# How to put Thinkpad X1 Extreme to sleep in Ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: suspend, thinkpad

Closing the lid of the Thinkpad does not put the laptop to sleep. Could you please tell me how to fix this? Also want to wake it up automatically when I open the lcd lid.

Comment: Solved here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/967205/where-is-the-suspend-hibernate-button-in-gnome-shell

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the suspend/hibernate button in GNOME Shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967205/where-is-the-suspend-hibernate-button-in-gnome-shell)

Comment: Works for me using the nVidia drivers installed by `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`. I didn't mess with GRUB kernel parameters or anything.