# 18.04 - Keep programs running after logging out

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, users, gnome-shell, workspaces

I have Ubuntu 18.04 freshly installed and up to date on a Dell Latitude 7490 and a docking station DisplayLink D3100 running 2 additional monitors.

I am trying to find a way to keep all the programs running after logging out with the default <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> shortcut.

Thank you for all your answers!

Comment: That is the expected behaviour. What are you trying achieve? Are you looking for some other alternatives like 'suspend' (aka 'sleep') or 'hibernation' or simply locking the screen?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am trying to keep all programs open as I have left them before logging out. Either hibernate or suspend is fine (former would be better I suppose, but it is not an issue).

Comment: Then please [edit] your question and mention clearly what you're *trying to achieve*. Currently it sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Logging out means you're ending the current computing session for the current user and thus programs getting killed after logging out is a normal and expected outcome. From the title and the body of your question it sounds like you are not at all expecting this to happen.

Comment: See this if you want to suspend instead: https://askubuntu.com/questions/967205/where-is-the-suspend-hibernate-button-in-gnome-shell

Comment: Alright, I did not know the logout meaning in Linux env. I have found a solution and I am updating the post accordingly. Thank you for helping me clarifying it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution can be found in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/763784/902897).
Replacing the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> shortcut command (Settings > Devices > Keyboard) with `systemctl suspend` lets you suspend the system and require the password on login.

Also I have found useful to set the Power Button to suspend on press, thanks to [pomsky's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1100684/18-04-keep-programs-running-after-logging-out#comment1814275_1100684).