# GNOME Shell extension 'Suspend Button' is not working in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I can't enable the Suspend Button extension:

[image]

[image]

Comment: ubuntu 20.04 ...

Comment: for 20.04 y0u already have suspend button.. and the extension you are looking to install is not for the gnome-shell version 3.36..

Comment: yes bt this not activating. look i posted another photo

Comment: that might be someother related.. edit the question to explain actual problem that suspend button in 20.04 is not working..

Comment: what i have to do now?

Comment: click on top right corner on your desktop.. see the power0ff/L0g 0ut menu.. there u hv suspend button.. dont install/try to install any extension for suspend button in Ububtu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

The [*Suspend Button* extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/826/suspend-button/) is officially supported up to GNOME Shell version `3.34` whereas Ubuntu 20.04 has version `3.36.x`. So rather unsurprisingly it doesn't work on Ubuntu 20.04.

On Ubuntu 20.04 you'll find the suspend option hidden under the '**Power Off / Log Out**' option in the system menu:
[image: GNOME 3.36 system menu]

Alternatively, you can search with the word "*suspend*" in *Activities or applications overview*; refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1136037/480481) from [Where is the suspend/hibernate button in GNOME Shell?](https://askubuntu.com/q/967205/480481)